# JS resolving a simple single promise rather than multiple

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to find out what the more suitable code is for resolving a *single* promise instead of multiple promises. I have this code which works correctly:

```
const products = await Promise.all([func1()])
```

But there is only one promise, yet the code uses `await Promise.all([promise])` but still works. I know it should be used for multiple promises like so:

```
const products = await Promise.all([func1(), func2(), func3()])
```

What is the correct code for just a single promise? I can't actually find the answer. Thanks

Comment: `await func1()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: none of that code is resolving a promise - it's all `await`ing the resolution of a single Promise - yes, Promise.all returns a single promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is only one promise, yet the code uses `await Promise.all([promise])` but still works.

Sure. In fact, you could have a empty array and it would still work, you'd get a promise that would be fulfilled instantly with an empty array. `Promise.all` doesn't care how many promises are in the iterable you give it. One, zero, many, doesn't matter.

If `func1` returns a promise and you just want that promise's fulfillment value:

```
const products = await func1();
```

Note that there, `products` will directly get the fulfillment value of `func1`, but with your original code, `products` will get an *array* with the fulfillment value of `func1` as entry 0.

You said you couldn't find the answer to this. I suspect you were looking for some `Promise.xyz` method to "handle" the promise. You didn't find it because it's not needed, `await` "handles" the promise. If you were trying to do this in a place you couldn't use `await`, then you'd see promise-specific stuff:

```
// **IF** you couldn't use `await`
func1()
.then(products => {
    // ...use products` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle promise rejection here...
});
```

But with `await`, that wiring (including propagating rejection to the caller) is done for you.

Comment: You're welcome! FWIW, I go into promises and `async`/`await` in depth in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.